# EMM - Device lock

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I were testing [General Device Operations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/General+Device+Operations) on my android tablet, and activate the device lock, and then removing it. but when I enter my password on my tablet it said 'wrong password'. Then I enterprise wipe so that emm setting eraised from my device.

The password was same as the pass using for encryption .It decrypt storage but didn't login to device.

Now I couldn't login to my device!

more info:

server = my windows laptop (install as a service)
client = Galexy Note 10

Edit:

After wiping the device, I also try to enter wrong password so that it reset factory. but it just count the attepts.

Edit 2:

I use [this](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-2079689/factory-reset-samsung-galaxy-note.html) to reset factory my tablet.

but I have a question how can I fix this issue. (screen password change during lock and unlocking device)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could do a clear password operation which is in EMM operations. It resets your screen lock password.

Anyways, if you forget your password and you do not have the EMM agent app in your phone / your data is cleared, you can do a hard reset to reset your phone. To do that, you have to switch off the phone and press Volume buttons + home button together and while pressing, you can power up the device. In the menu you get, first press volume up to go to boot menu. From there select wipe option and then reboot. But this will reset entire data partition + will also reset all the hardware drivers as well.

Thanks

Comment: There is no clear password operation in EMM. which operation do you mean?

Comment: In device detailed view/device listing don't you see an operation named "Clear" ? If not can you go to Configurations/Roles and check permissions for your user roles? Check whether "Clear" option is ticked under operations and if not, tick that option and save changes. Then you will see the operation. If none of these suggestions work for you, we will have to go further and check your DB level.

Comment: It didn't work on that time (by 'removing it' in question I mean using clear operation). should I enable something before it?

Comment: No. If the operation request has gone to the device, it should clear the passcode. If you had your internet connection up, it should work. Are you sure you had proper connectivity by the time you did this? I have tried this in a fresh EMM pack and it worked for me without a hassle. If this issue is persisting in your pack, we will have to debug this.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, I will check this again.